# When laravel user session cleared on session expired?

Tags: php, laravel-8

In Laravel config/Session.php set lifetime => 5 -> session will expired after 5 minutes

After the user logged in & the user is idle for 5 or more than 5 minutes the user session is cleared. I'm trying to find out which piece of code is used to clear the user session & redirected to the login page.

can anyone guide me on this how to find out when the session is cleared?

Comment: PHP will clear the session. When you find that whatever you store in the session is missing, you redirect to whereever you want, the login if you like

Comment: actually, I've to update the user status in the database before the session expired